# How do I hierarchically cluster column containing multiple categorical variables in r?

Tags: r, categorical-data, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to do some hierarchical clustering on some movie data and ran into a conceptual issue with a column containing the movie genres. The column will code genres as a string of integers separated by commas and has a separate coding manual to distinguish what integers represent which genres (E.g. Movie 1 has genres "1,2,3" which correspond to "Action" "Comedy" and "Romance" in a separate sheet) and these codes don't necessarily come in the same order (A similar movie's generes could be encoded as "2,1,3").

The problem is that many movies tend to have a different # of genres and if I were to use the separate() function from tidyr I would be left with a lot of missing cells and, when it comes time to run hierarchical clustering / a pairwise similarity algorithm across the rows/movies, I'm afraid of there being 1. unequal weight being given to movies with more genres and 2. cases where movies with the same genres won't be counted as similar because the columns won't line up properly

Does anyone have any suggestions on properly clustering this type of data?

Comment: One small suggestion: before splitting into separate columns, sort the codes in increasing order, so that "1, 3, 2" and "1, 2, 3" would end up being the same thing.

Comment: (Far) better: encode the genres as binary vectors.  This permits you to construct a suitable distance function.  However, there are many other possible solutions.  Selecting a good one depends (partly) on how you conceptualize and quantify the distance.

Comment: @whuber By encoding them as binary vectors do you mean the following: Say there are 5 genres (Action, Comedy, Romance, Mystery, Horror) and I encode them as a vector in that order. For Movie 1 listed above, instead of separating it into 3 columns, I would instead encode it as c(1,1,1,0,0) and Movie 2 would also be c(1,1,1,0,0)?

Comment: Yes.  And that nicely illustrates one natural distance, the Hamming distance: it is the number of components that differ.  But you can define plenty of other distances between vectors (now that you have them), such as any $L_p$ distance, a weighted $L_p$ distance, a cosine distance, etc.